# Выбор элемента DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Выбирается третий элемент в dataGridVie2, хотя нажимаю на любой. Как сделать чтобы в dataGridView2.Rows[2] был то элемент на который кликнет пользователь?

```
        string Data = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value);
        string Url = "http://project-megaroks931128.codeanyapp.com/news/add/?usersid=" + Data;
        string json = RequestJson(Url);
        ResponseJson(json);
        His(Data, json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял , вам нужен индекс ячейки по которой кликнул пользователь , в таком случае код:

```csharp
int selRowIndex = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло